# SOAP Client PHP

Tags: php, soap

Здравствуйте!

До сего момента не приходилось отправлять параметры по SOAP. Сейчас возникла нужда сформировать вот такую структуру параметра:

```
<wsLoginPassword xsi:type="java:WsLoginPassword" xmlns:java="java:com.nt.slib.ws.wssearch">
<wslogin xsi:type="xsd:string">YOUR_LOGIN</wslogin>
<wspassword xsi:type="xsd:string">your_password</wspassword>
</wsLoginPassword>
```

Делаю вот что:

```
$params = array(
new SoapVar('login', 'wslogin'), 
new SoapVar('123', 'wspassword')
);
$var = new SoapVar(Array('wsLoginPassword' => $params), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'wsLoginPassword', 'http://www.natalie-tours.ru/webservices');
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.natalie-tours.ru/webservice/BookingWS?WSDL', array('trace' => 1));
$client->getAllRegions($var);
```

После выполнения пишет что логин не верный. Предполагаю, что запрос кривой.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Я пытался работать с SOAP в PHP. Ну... это был ад) В итоге я под проект написал тупой хттп-клиент, формировал вручную запросы и тд. 

Почему? Потому что php-шный soapclient добавляет в теги какие-то свои неймспейсы, иногда меняет местами теги, не следит за кодировкой и еще какие-то финты мне выдавал типа отказа загружать WSDL. Возможно, все это лечится, но я за неделю эротических утех с этим порождением ада устал.

Если за день-два не найдете способа лучше - поделюсь наработками.

Comment: Никогда бы не подумал, что все настолько плохо. Спасибо за ответ - пока пытаемся найти решение.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше поздно чем никогда, сам долго с этим разбирался, может кому еще поможет.

Я реализовывал бы немного по-другому (по крайней мере там где я пишу Soap запросы делаю это следующим образом). 
Для переменных, из которых будет формироваться хмлка soap запроса, делаем классы. Смотрим в wsdl(я залез по ссылке которую вы привели в коде), сначала операцию которую вызываем для клиента:

```
<operation name="getAllRegions">
   <input message="tns:getAllRegions"></input>
   <output message="tns:getAllRegionsResponse"></output>
</operation>
```

Видим, тут на вход принимается переменная типа getAllRegions, это можно посмотреть в описании сообщения

```
<message name="getAllRegions">
  <part name="parameters" element="partns:getAllRegions"></part>
</message>
```

Ищем где он описан:

```
<xsd:element name="getAllRegions">
 <xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element type="tp:WsLoginPassword" name="wsLoginPassword></xsd:element>
     </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
```

Ага, раз так, то нам еще надо описать еще и WsLoginPassword из которого он состоит:

```
<xsd:complexType name="WsLoginPassword">
 <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="wslogin" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"></xsd:element>
  <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="wspassword" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"></xsd:element>
 </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Ну и погнали:

```
class getAllRegions{
  public $WsLoginPassword
}

class WsLoginPassword{
  public $wslogin;
  public $wspassword;
}

try{
$requestClass = new getAllRegions();
$requestClass->WsLoginPassword = new WsLoginPassword();
$requestClass->WsLoginPassword->wslogin = 'login';
$requestClass->WsLoginPassword->wspassword = '123';
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.natalie-tours.ru/webservice/BookingWS?WSDL', 
                                 [
                                     'trace' => true,
                                     'exceptions'=>true
                                 ]);
$client->getAllRegions($requestClass);
}catch (SoapFault $e){
  //тут из клиента во время дебага можно посмотреть или
  // через echo настроить вывод содержимого. В 
  // $client->__getLastResponse() содержится что тебе ответил сервис,
  // а в $client->__getLastRequest() какую xml клиент отправит на сервак
  // после обработки классов выше. В $e будет текст ошибки.
}
```